# How to logical and (^ , logical conjunction) string lists - C#

Tags: c#, string, list, compare, logical-operators

Alright. Now this question may come to you weird but i have to solve it. Now the issue is simple. Let me explain with good example

Lets say that i have the following string lists. Each line is a list and those lists will be logical anded [image]

```
my,car,fly,surf,buy
house,home,car,fly,buy
fly,king,rock,buy,sell
fly,buy,home,rock,sell
```

Alright if you logically and the above lists the result would be

```
fly,buy
```

Because those 2 are the only same elements in those lists. Now how can i achieve this fastest run time way with C# 4.0 ? Thank you

c# , c#-4.0

Comment: Fastest in terms of runtime, or fastest in terms of development time?  Also, I would recommend against optimizing runtime until you have a correct solution. [Insert obligatory Knuth quote here]

Comment: Now it is fastest run time not development time. Thank you. Though i still would like to hear fastest development time methods too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb293080.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<T> IntersectAll(IEnumerable<T> lists)
{
    var set = new HashSet<T>(lists.First());

    foreach (var other in lists.Skip(1))
    {
        set.IntersectWith(other);
    }

    return set;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best and easiest implementable solution :) Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) method given by LINQ.  For instance:

```
List<string> a = new List<string>() {"my","car","fly","surf","buy"};
List<string> b = new List<string>() {"house","home","car","fly","buy" };

var c = a.Intersect(b);
```

Gives car, fly, and buy.  Repeat the intersection on `c` for the rest of your strings to get the full intersection.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<List<string>> lists = //whatever
HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>(lists[0]);

for(int i = 1; i < lists.Count; i++)
{
    set.IntersectWith(lists[i]);
}
```

Using linq you can use:

```
var intersection = lists.Aggregate((l1, l2) => l1.Intersect(l2).ToList());
```